# ODE Non - Homogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is:
$$y''-2y'+1=0$$

I am trying to find the general solution and have tried a few different tactics. I can't use the char equation because it won't work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could set $ w=y' $ to get $w'-2w+1=0$. Also, the characteritic equation works for the associated homogeneous DE $y_h''-2y_h'=0$. You could also use variation of parameters or undetermined coefficients to find the particular solution.

Comment: Integrate both sides.

Answer (score 0):

$$y''-2y'+1=0$$
$$y''-2y'=-1$$
Just integrate both sides:
$$\int (y''-2y')dx=-\int dx$$
$$\int dy'-2\int dy=-\int dx$$
$$y'-2y=-x+C_1$$
The DE is of first order apply any method you know to integrate the DE.

---

Note that :
$$y''-2y'+1=0$$
becomes homogeneous:
$$(y-\dfrac x2)''-2(y-\dfrac x2)' =0$$
$$u''-2u'=0$$
With $u=y-\dfrac x2$.
$$\implies r^2-2r=r(r-2)=0 $$
$$r=0, r=2$$
Therefore
$$u=c_1e^{2x}+c_2$$
$$y=c_1e^{2x}+c_2+\dfrac x2$$

Answer (score 0):

If you do as Matthew Pilling suggests, you can see that there are *only* derivatives there.  So this means that you can set $w = y'$ and therefore $w' = y''$ and this becomes a first order equation.

$$ w' - 2w + 1 = 0 \\
w' = 2w - 1 \\
\frac{w'}{2w - 1} = 1 \\
\frac{dw}{2w - 1} = dx \\
\int \frac{dw}{2w - 1} = \int dx \\
\frac{1}{2}\ln(2w - 1) = x + C \\
\ln(2w - 1) = 2x + C \\
2w - 1 = Ce^{2x} \\
2y' - 1 = Ce^{2x} \\
2\,dy - dx = Ce^{2x}\,dx \\
2\int dy - \int dx = \int Ce^{2x}\,dx \\
2y - x = Ce^{2x} + D \\
y = Ce^{2x} + \frac{1}{2}x + D
$$
Reminder, C & D don't change with constant transformations, as they remain unknown constants.